# Using the GPUImageFilter library in android

Tags: android, gpuimage

i m new to android and after having long search and also tried some java code for implement filter effect like the instagram so going with java code filter effect are working but too slow,so week before stop using that effect and after search found one library GPUImageFilter(on github) and start working on that library .The library for filter effect work very fine and produce some good effect also and i m able to implement in my project also but the next thing arise as after saving the image with filter in the sdcard ,if again i try to fetch that file from the sdcard it showing nothing but blank screen and if we look inside the device sdcard it showing as file is saved and opening in the gallery also.can any tell me how to overcome this problem.Here is the link where u can find the lib:

link:-[GPUImageFilter library](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage)

any help will be very much helpfull to me.Thanks and waiting for reply.

Comment: It sounds like your question is more about saving images properly than filtering them. Could you show the code you're using for saving these filtered images?

Comment: yeah your are right and thanks for reply.Got the solution and the problem is in providing correct path i.e start from /mnt/..../foldername/.../filename while fetching from it sdcard.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, I am displaying the Images in a `ListView` using a `GPUImageView`. The Images are being displayed for the First time, but when i do scrolling in the `ListView`, all the scrolled `GPUImageViews` display blank.